# Attribute value out of range exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XAML parse Exception: Attribute {StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush} value is out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006100/xaml-parse-exception-attribute-staticresource-phoneaccentbrush-value-is-out-o)

recently i am starting win phone 7 programing in c#. for first time i take a button and textbox only.In button click function i wrote:

```
private void ClickMeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            BannerTextBlock.Text = MessageTextBox.Text;
            MessageTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
        }
```

then i receive an error message **in file:**MainPage.g.i.cs

> **in line:** System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/WindowsPhoneApplication2;component/MainPage.xaml",
>   System.UriKind.Relative));
>
> **error message:** Attribute {StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush} value is out of range. [Line: 39 Position: 138]

I can not find any solution in Microsoft's own site. what can I do?

**XAML content of  UI:**

```
       <phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
       x:Class="WindowsPhoneApplication2.MainPage"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
       xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
       FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
         FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
       Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
       SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
       shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

       <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



     <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
     <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" 
     Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" 
       Style="  {StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>

    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="MessageTextBox"  
        FontSize="{StaticResource  PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Margin="20,20,10,477"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Name="ClickMeButton" Content="Click Me"  
         HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="4" Margin="0,20,20,477"
           Style="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" DataContext="{Binding}" 
                Click="ClickMeButton_Click" />
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,477">
            <TextBlock Name="BannerTextBlock" 
             Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" 
           Foreground="#FFFF9A00" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold"   
            Margin="12,0,12,491" />
        </Grid>
         </Grid>
         </Grid>

          <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
          <!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png"  
           Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" 
          Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            </shell:ApplicationBar>
             </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->

            </phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: Looks like you've got an invalid StaticResource in your XAML. Can you post the XAML content of your UI?

Comment: The error there is telling you that the problem is in your xaml code and not within the button code. Try looking in that on the line/position it tells you. Posting that part of the code might help too. Are you trying to set PhoneAccentBrush to a style? It might be similar to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006100/xaml-parse-exception-attribute-staticresource-phoneaccentbrush-value-is-out-o The other thing though here is that you are emptying the MessageTextBox before using it. You probably want to switch those statements around

Comment: I think you need to edit your post to add in the xaml. Pasting into a comment won't be so useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Firedragon, you're setting a `Brush` as the value for a `Style`. Which obviously are not the same thing.

The problem is here:

```
<Button Name="ClickMeButton" Style="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" ...
```

This is not valid. What you probably wanted to do, was something like:

```
<Button Name="ClickMeButton" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" ...
```